# Get all records participating in group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query that returns the records that are participating in group by clause using count(*) function.
For example I have a table called books like

```
======================
 ID | NAME |  AUTHER
======================
 2  | Abc  | John 
 6  | Abc  | John 
 3  | Xyz  | Mike 
 4  | Abc  | Mike 
 5  | Xyz  | John 
 1  | Abc  | Mike 
 7  | PQR  | Raj
```

For this if I write a query like

```
select count(*),name,auther from books group by(name,auther);
```

then it returns the records like

```
========================
COUNT(*)| NAME |AUTHER
========================
1       | Xyz  | Mike 
1       | PQR  | Raj 
2       | Abc  | John 
1       | Xyz  | John 
2       | Abc  | Mike
```

Now I want to know the id of the books which are in same group. 
For example in last record of result there are two books so what will be the ID of them ?

Comment: Which of RDBMs are you actually using, MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply..I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get a comma seperated list of ids

```
select count(*),name, auther, group_concat(id) ids
from books 
group by name, auther;
```

Comment: is group_concat mysql function ?

Comment: Yes it is. See the link to the doc?

Comment: Thanks a lot..is it possible to get whole records not only the ids ?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want all records why group in the first place?

Comment: I want to achieve the group wise records.